# EWS SOAP Open Folder given uint8_t ID

Tags: xml, soap, exchangewebservices, mapi

Using the EWS API, I am given a `const uint8_t *longTermID` and its `uint32_t idSize` to use to open a folder. In our old MAPI code, we would call [`GetIdFromLongTermId`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/intrepid/man3/IUnknown.c.3.html) using some types defined in the MAPI headers. I can't seem to find anything equivalent for using a `uint8_t` ID to open a folder for EWS. I tried

[ConvertId Operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb799665%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) with `EntryId` as the `AlternateId Format` to a `DestinationFormat` of `EwsId` but that result fails.

This is the first time I've worked on exchange server stuff, and all of this was previously done by a developer who no longer works here.

I've tried to change it to a string via `string id(longTermID, longTermID+idSize)` but that just produces a blank string.

Would I want something like [GetItem operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa566013%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you're taking a byte array that represents the EntryId of an item and you're trying to get the EWS ItemId or FolderId from it. Did you convert that byte array to a base 64 string (EntryId) or a hex string (HexEntryId) prior to submitting the ConvertId request? I believe that's what EWS requires. A straight string conversion won't do it.

Comment: So running the `longTermID` through a base64 encode worked, and the request returned an `EwsID`. However, `GetFolder` is responding with a malformed ID. I'm giving it the `EwsID` returned by the `ConvertId` operation.

Comment: FolderId and ItemId in EWS are not the same thing. You can't use GetFolder with an ItemId as far as I know. You can get the ParentFolderId from the Item.